# Why do Apache Common dependencies conflict under sbt-onejar while sbt run works?

Tags: java, sbt, apache-commons

My project is depending directly on `commons-configuration` (1.6), but is also pulling transitively:
`commons-beanutils-core` (1.8.0) and `commons-collections` (3.2.1).

These last 2 seem to conflict with eachother, maybe because they both define classes in package `org.apache.commons.collections`. I am supposing that, because when running the resulting jar (packaged with sbt plugin `sbt-onejar`), I see a lot of errore in output like:

> JarClassLoader: Warning:
>   org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap.class in
>   lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar is hidden by
>   lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (with different bytecode)

Strangely, this does not appear when I just "sbt run" (instead of producing a one-jar and running it manually).

Am I doing something wrong, or is there really a conflict within the libs ?

Comment: That must be some sbt-onejar-woodoo that I can't explain. Since it works with `sbt run`, I'm wondering what you need sbt-onejar for? Could sbt-native-packager be of any help (and perhaps would not present the issue)?

Comment: It seems to work fine with sbt-native-packager indeed (using "stage"). However, this produces a lot of files, while I'd like to keep the "app = 1 file" model for now (the app itself is still small and has few dependencies, so size is not a problem) for easier deployment.

Comment: Someone reported a similar problem: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar/issues/9, and sbt-onejar author suggested fixing the classpath. But in that case the person was using 2 different versions of the same lib. In my case the duplicates come from different commons libs.

Comment: Ah, right. Your main goal is to have a single app in a single jar with all the dependencies and other files bundled.

Comment: I also found a related [apache issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEANUTILS-379). This doesn't explain (to me) why things work with just "sbt run", but there definetly seems to be something wrong in the commons libraries set.

Comment: Unfortunately while beanutils seems fixed in versions 1.9+, I could not find a configurations version depending on such recent version.
So my solution/workaround is to disable a (apparently unneeded) dependency:

`libraryDependencies += "commons-configuration" % "commons-configuration" % "1.6" excludeAll(
  ExclusionRule(organization = "commons-beanutils", name = "commons-beanutils-core"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "commons-beanutils", name = "commons-beanutils")
  )`

Comment: Could you add the comment as an answer and accept?

Comment: I thought about doing that but it is not really answering the question (especially formulated as "why ..."). So I wrote the comment in case someone searched for that error, leaving the question open for someone who can explain why. But if you think making it an answer would make my solution more visible, I can do it.

Comment: Fair enough. I went ahead and offered mine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to learn about the dependencies with `sbt update` and reviewing the reports under `target/resolution-cache/reports`. They're for every configuration in your build.

If you could update your build to sbt 0.13.6 (in `project/build.properties`), you could use `evicted` task. Read https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v0.13.6:

> sbt 0.13.6 displays eviction warnings when it resolves your project's managed dependencies via update task.

and later

> To display all eviction warnings with caller information, run evicted task.

It may also give you an insight on the dependencies versions.

Once you've figured out what dependency brings a given version of the affected class you could `excludeAll` it ([as you've ultimately done given the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143080/why-do-apache-common-dependencies-conflict-under-sbt-onejar-while-sbt-run-works?noredirect=1#comment41450797_26143080)).

Comment: I am not sure what "eviction" really means. From reading the release notes, I'd say it only looks into dependencies versions and warns when 2 different conflicting versions are pulled.

In my case the conflict comes from duplicate classes in 2 differently named libs. Maybe that's why I'm not getting any warning with sbt 0.13.6, doing "update" or "evicted" (nor with "one-jar").